# Probability of minimum size of intersection of two subsets

Tags: probability

NOTE: This is a question I came up with and cannot figure out relating to how few topics (A $\subset$ T) out of total possible topics (T) I could study for to have a good chance of adequately knowing at least 3 topics from (B $\subset$ T) that would appear on a philosophy exam. The most similar distribution I could find it Hypergeometric distribution, however it is for exactly $k$ but I am looking for at least $k=3$.

Let size of $T$ = 10

Let size of $A \subset T$ = 7

Let size of $B \subset T$ = 5

What is the probability that size of $(A \cap B) \geq 3$ ?

Answer (score 3):

If the topics on the exam are chosen uniformly at random, and you choose the topics to study uniformly at random (both of which assumptions strain my credulity, I must say) then you have $\binom{10}{7}$ ways to choose the topics.  To choose at least $3$ from $B$ you may choose:

$3$ from $B$ and $4$ from $B^c,$

$4$ from $B$ and $3$ from $B^c,$

$5$ from $B$ and $2$ from $B^c.$

The probability is $$\frac{2\binom{5}{3}\binom{5}{4}+\binom{5}{2}}{\binom{10}{7}}$$

Comment: You only need one of the two, either the topics on the exam or the topics studied, to be uniform for your analysis to be correct.  This may reduce the strain on your credulity a bit.

Comment: @RossMillikan Of course; it doesn't matter how the professor picks the topics.

Comment: shouldn't the numerator rather be: $2{5}\choose{3} + 2{5}\choose{4} + {5}\choose{2}$ ?

Comment: @Jabar No, because he chooses 7 subjects.  Besides the ones he chooses that appear on the exam, you have to consider the ones that do not appear on the exam.  ($B^c$ means "B complement.")

Answer (score 2):

Only possibility for $A\cap B <3$ is that, $B$ has all 3 elements from $T- A$. 
Count how many ways you can select $2$ elements out of $7$:
\begin{equation}
1-\frac{\binom{3}{3}\binom{7}{2}}{\binom{10}{5}} = 
1 - \frac{\binom{7}{2}}{\binom{10}{5}}
\end{equation} 
with the assumption that any combination has equal probability.